# Does UK visa refusal affect my Schengen visa application

Tags: uk, schengen, visa-refusals, schengen-visas

I applied for UK visa back in 2016 when I was doing my training and was taking stipend with not enough funds. now I am in an active job for the last 5 years with enough funds.

Now I am applying for Schengen visa. do we have to disclose UK visa refusal while applying for Schengen visa? as they have asked only about previous Schengen refusals and not about any UK refusals.

Answer (score 3):

When applying for visa, you should answer truthfully all the questions asked of you.

On the other hand, you are not obligated to answer questions that are not asked. The UK is not (and has never been) a Schengen member.

Thus, if the question asks about prior *Schengen* refusal, then the answer is "No."